# Iterate over filtered values of a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(year= c(2001:2005,2001:2005,2001:2005),
                income = sample(2000:10000,15,replace = T),
                gender = sample(1:2,15,replace = T),
                education = sample(1:3,15,replace = T)
)
```

Since in the actual dataframe, I have more variables than just `gener` and `education`, I want to write a function to plot income kernel densities for each subgroup vs. all under gender and education, and save as pdf for each subgroup at the end.
Take `gender==1` as an example:

```
male <- d %>% filter(gender == 1)

density_all <- density(d$income)
density_male <- density(male$income)

d_densisty <- data.frame(x = density_all$x, 
                      density_all = density_all$y, 
                      density_male = density_male$y)

plot <- ggplot(d_densisty, aes(x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = density_all), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = density_male), color = "blue")

ggsave("subgroup_name.pdf", plot, width = 300, height = 250, units = "mm")
```

I have thought about converting the dataframe from long to wide format, but the length of each subgroup won't be the same.
I also thought about doing a loop within a loop, i.e. first looping over the values in a variable (gender == 1 or 2), then looping over the variables (gender and education). Not sure which option is better and how exactly I can carry it out.

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify by using `geom_density()`:    `ggplot(d) + geom_density(aes(x = income, color = as.factor(gender))) + geom_density(aes(x = income))` - needs some tweaking but may get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ```geom_density()``` is very helpful. But I think I didn't make it clear enough. I want to generate several plots, and save each plot as a pdf, instead drawing of several lines in one plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store all the plots in a list of lists, just amend the initial vector for the variables you wish to cover:

```
plots <- map(.x = c("gender", "education"),
             .f = \(categ){
               map(.x = unique(d[[categ]]),
                   .f = \(lev){
                     plt <- ggplot(d) +
                       geom_density(aes(x = income, colour = "red")) +
                       geom_density(data = d[d[categ]== lev,], aes(x = income, colour = "blue"))
                   })
             })
```

You can use `walk()` on the lists to apply your save-to-pdf function, but I assume you'll want to play with the aesthetics, set titles, hide the legend etc first.

EDIT:
Version allowing for plotting of the difference as well:

```
plots <- map(.x = c("gender", "education"),
             .f = \(categ){
               tmpdf <- data.frame(x = density(d$income)$x, 
                                   y = density(d$income)$y)
               map(.x = unique(d[[categ]]),
                   .f = \(lev){
                     tmpdf$y2 <- density(d[d[[categ]] == lev,"income"])$y
                     tmpdf$y3 <- tmpdf$y - tmpdf$y2
                     plt <- ggplot(cbind(tmpdf, density(d[d[[categ]] == lev,"income"])$y)) +
                       geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = "total")) +
                       geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y2, colour = "filtered")) +
                       geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y3, colour = "difference")) +
                       scale_color_manual(name = categ, values = c("total" = "red",
                                                                   "filtered" = "blue",
                                                                   "difference" = "black"))
                   })
             })
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I got the error messages: ```Error: unexpected input in:
"plots <- map(.x = c("gender", "education"), .f = \"  Error: unexpected input in:
"map(.x = unique(d[[categ]]), .f = \" Error in `[.data.frame`(d, categ) : object 'categ' not found Error: unexpected '}' in " }```

Comment: What version of R are you using?  You may need to use `function(categ){` instead of `\(categ){` for the anonymous function there.

Comment: R 4.0.3. Yes, ```function(categ){" solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can I change the code to use ```geom_line( )``` instead of ```geom_density```, because I also want to plot a line to show the difference between ```density_all``` and ```density_subgroup```.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think the best way would be to change the function inside the inner `map()` call to be closer to the example in your OP - create a temporary copy of your dataframe in which you can calculate the densities yourself and add the difference as another new column, then use geom_line() for the plotting.

Comment: have a look at the edit and see it that helps